# SafeBox StateMachine implemented with Enums

Tags: java, enum, state-machine

does someone has any opinions about this SafeBox StateMachine?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SafeBoxStateMachine {

    public enum SafeBox {

        ACCEPT{     
            private Scanner scan;
            private boolean askPassword(SafeBoxStateMachine safebox){

                System.out.println("Please type a password:");
                scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                String buffer = scan.nextLine();

                if (buffer.equals(safebox.password) == false){
                    ++safebox.counter;
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }   
            }
            public void process(SafeBoxStateMachine safebox){

                boolean res = askPassword(safebox);

                if (res == false) 
                    System.out.println("try number:" + safebox.counter);

                if (safebox.counter == 3){

                    safebox.state = SafeBox.PENELTY;                
                }

                if (res == true)
                {
                    safebox.state = SafeBox.SUCCESS;        
                }   
            }           
        }, 
        PENELTY{
            public void process(SafeBoxStateMachine safebox){
                System.out.println("7 seconds penalty!");
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(7000); 
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }   
                safebox.counter = 0;
                safebox.state = SafeBox.ACCEPT;
            }       
        }, 
        SUCCESS{
            public void process(SafeBoxStateMachine safebox){

                System.out.println("Success!");
                safebox.stop = true;
            }

        };

        abstract public void process(SafeBoxStateMachine safebox);  
    }

    int counter = 0;    
    private SafeBox state = SafeBox.ACCEPT; 
    String password;
    boolean stop = false;

    SafeBoxStateMachine (String password){
        this.password = password;
        counter = 0;
    }

    public void run(){
        while (stop == false)           
            this.state.process(this);
    }

    public void setPass(String pass){
        this.password = pass;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SafeBoxStateMachine pass = new SafeBoxStateMachine("hello");

        pass.run();

    }

}
```

Comment: You can use the state Design Pattern. Please refer the link https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-state.  Please modify the code  put for review.

Answer (score 2):

#### Make fields immutable when possible

The `setPass` method is never used in the posted code.
As such, you can make the `password` field immutable:

```
private final String password;
```

#### Reuse `Scanner`

`ACCEPT.askPassword` will recreate the `Scanner scan` field from `System.in` every time it's called. This is unnecessary, it would be better to create the scanner only once.
That also means that you can make `scan` a `final` field.

#### Use boolean expressions directly

Instead of code like this:

> ```
> if (res == false)
> // ...
>
> if (res == true)
> // ...
> ```

Use boolean expressions directly like this:

```
if (!res)
// ...

if (res)
// ...
```

Do this everywhere where you used `something == true` or `false`.

#### Combine related `if` statements

In this code there are two conditions on the value of `res`:

> ```
> if (res == false) 
>     System.out.println("try number:" + safebox.counter);
>
> if (safebox.counter == 3){
>
>     safebox.state = SafeBox.PENELTY;                
> }
>
> if (res == true)
> {
>     safebox.state = SafeBox.SUCCESS;        
> }
> ```

The code could be reorganized to make it clearer and to avoid one unnecessary condition:

```
if (safebox.counter == 3) {
    safebox.state = SafeBox.PENELTY;
}

if (res) {
    safebox.state = SafeBox.SUCCESS;
} else {
    System.out.println("try number:" + safebox.counter);
}
```

And since `safebox.counter` is only incremented in case of failure,
the penalty condition can be moved inside the `else` branch of the second `if` statement:

```
if (askPassword(safebox)) {
    safebox.state = SafeBox.SUCCESS;
} else {
    System.out.println("try number:" + safebox.counter);
    if (safebox.counter == 3) {
        safebox.state = SafeBox.PENELTY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Janos. Yet again another great review - fixed it all in accordance to your recommendations. they all make sense. 
tnx!